# MySQL Join Table with String of other Records

Tags: mysql

Can you help me cause all the records in the "`preference`" table to become a `string` inside the `p.data` returned result?

I could only think of `CONCAT`, but my inner join only selects 1 record.

**Example Query**

```
SELECT 
    u.userid, 
    p.data

FROM user u

INNER JOIN preference p ON (
  p.userid = u.userid
)

WHERE u.userid = 1
```

**Desired Output**

```
userid  |  data
--------------
1       | 1,2,3,4,5
2       | 1,2,3,4
3       | 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) performs exactly this function:

```
SELECT
  u.userid,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.data) AS data
FROM
  user u
  INNER JOIN preference p ON u.userid = p.userid
WHERE u.userid = 1
GROUP BY u.userid
```

You only get one row back because of your `WHERE` clause. Remove the `WHERE` clause to return rows for all users.  And switch it to a `LEFT JOIN` if you want to return users having no related rows in the `preference` table.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't matter your Inner join only join one field.
You have to add group by

```
SELECT 
    u.userid, 
    GroupConcat(p.data) as Data

FROM user u

INNER JOIN preference p ON (
  p.userid = u.userid
)
--WHERE u.userid = 1 With this you not gonna get the desired output.
group by u.userId
```

Comment: Thanks, just has to be GROUP_CONCAT!